# Consent Management

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are building our target architecture and have come across a question when it comes to where we should build our global consent calculations. Specifically, all the rules globally that determine whether we can email someone or not. For example, in Canada, we have implicit consent for 2 years if someone makes a purchase… in Germany, the person must have a double opt in… if someone signs up for the brand A then we have consent for brand B , etc…

Would the recommendation to build these rules in Salesforce marketing cloud (via SQLs or SSJS) or put it in an external system /process  that calculates consent and then feeds that into SFMC. Other systems may need to know the consent for a subscriber as well. 
Interested to hear experiences on this topic.

Comment: What system is the source of the data in Marketing Cloud? Is it Sales Cloud or is it a different CRM system?

Comment: it is another system , a data warehouse that pushes contact and sales data to Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to manage the consent in your source of truth, in your case is your data warehouse. An important point to take into account is the time-frequency the date is synchronized with Marketing Cloud to check if it is necessary to create an intermediate process in Marketing Cloud or not.